# why didn't use lock to sync in log package

Tags: logging, go

I'm reading [log source code](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go?s=8938:8966#L289),I'm confused in here:

```
// SetOutput sets the output destination for the standard logger.
func SetOutput(w io.Writer) {
    std.mu.Lock()
    defer std.mu.Unlock()
    std.out = w
}

// Flags returns the output flags for the standard logger.
func Flags() int {
    return std.Flags()
}

// SetFlags sets the output flags for the standard logger.
func SetFlags(flag int) {
    std.SetFlags(flag)
}
```

why `SetOutPut` use `mu` to lock but `SetFlags` don't use `mu` to lock?

Comment: Because [SetFlags already does](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/27d5c0ede5b4411089f4bf52a41dd2f4eed36123/src/log/log.go#L230). The really interesting question is, why *do* they use locks in `SetOutput` instead of just doing `std.SetOutput(w)`.

Comment: @Ainar-G: Logger didn't always have its own SetOutput method. (added in 1.5 I think)

Comment: @JimB [You're right](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#minor_library_changes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetOutput` is altering the internal state of the `std` default Logger.

`log.SetFlags` is calling [`SetFlags`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger.SetFlags) on `std`, which already locks the logger itself.